# Conditional sum in Group By query Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a viewtable with the following schema:

```
No_quotation        |period   |total_hour
001/QY-RKS/05/2016  Mar-16      21.0
001/QY-RKS/05/2016  Mar-16      21.0
002/QY-RKS/05/2016  Apr-16      18.0
002/QY-RKS/05/2016  Apr-16      18.0
```

i need to sum the table like this

```
No_quotation        |period   |total_hour
001/QY-RKS/05/2016  Mar-16      42.0
002/QY-RKS/05/2016  Apr-16      36.0
```

Comment: Seems like you know everything, what's the problem?

Comment: `select ...., sum(total_hour) group by No_quotation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do an aggregation of the `total_hour` column for each `No_quotation`/`period` group:

```
SELECT No_quotation, period, SUM(total_hour) AS total_hour
FROM viewtable
GROUP BY No_quotation, period
```